# Upgrade problem ubuntu 18.04 (Not fully installed)

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

I have upgraded my 16.04 to 18.04 to but it is not looking like 18.04

[image]

[image: Its not looking like 18.04]

Comment: After the upgrade, Unity would probably still remain the default desktop. I guess you should have an option to switch to Gnome now though on your login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you still have the Unity desktop environment, rather than GNOME (which is the default desktop in 18.04). Try restarting and clicking on the gear icon when you sign in. Then select "Ubuntu". If this does not work, try typing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` in the Terminal, restarting and trying to select a different desktop again.